# How to initialize all the values of a two dimensional array using Ruby, is there any way to do it in 1 step?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

For example, initialize the entire array to 0 or any other value.

```
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed your array that was not a valid array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I assign default values for two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599437/how-do-i-assign-default-values-for-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure

```
Array.new(3) { Array.new(4, 0) }
 => [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Eduard, a variant of this answer is `Array.new(3) { Array.new(4) { 0 } }`. You need to understand that this answer is not the same as `arr = Array.new(3, Array.new(4, 0)) #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`. The latter would be incorrect, for if we set `arr[0][0] = 1` we would find `arr #=> [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]`. See [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new).

Comment: @CarySwoveland : May I suggest thta you post this as answer instead of a comment, because **this** seems to really be the anwer to the OPs problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland putting `0` in an extra block is superfluous because integers are immutable. Ursus' answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah, obviously I tried and there is no need for the extra block

Comment: @Stefan and Ursus, I was not advocating the variant; I mentioned it only to alert Eduard in case he saw it written that way.

Comment: Someone took it that way because I've received a downvote :D